# Hyperlink not correct with addcontentsline

Tags: hyperref

In this MWE, I used addcontentsline and hyperref.
The link appears in the table of contents but it doesn’t bring me to the correct page:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
   
This is the first section.
      
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\cleardoublepage
       
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

PS: I used my iPad to write this post and so there is no CTRL K to format the code. Sorry about that

Comment: add \phantomsection before the \addcontentsline to create an anchor.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer It works perfectly

Comment: Thank you@cabohah I had made a research but didn’t find this page

Comment: @Didier BTW: From time to time I also use my iPad. You can mark code by selecting it and click to the `{}` icon in the toolbar. Or you can add a line ```latex before the code and the same without latex after the code.

Comment: Thank you@cabohah I didn’t know that. Very useful